# Project dependencies in a nuget package are being copied to the application bin folder despite being marked PrivateAssets

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, project-reference, msbuild-projectreference

I have .netcore2.0 app called MyHelper.
MyHelper is referencing a .netstandard2.0 project called B.
MyHelper is published as a nuget package.

I need to use MyHelper in other projects and solutions only at build time, therefore in my other projects I mark this nuget package as private:

```
<PackageReference Include="MyHelper" Version="1.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

However in the output folder of my other projects consuming this nuget package, B.dll is being present.
I do not want that, as it is meant to be only for build time.
How do I stop it from being shipped to the applications.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` does not work for your situation. When you use this node in **Project C**, it will prevent another project called **Project D** which has a project reference to **Project C** not accessing the nuget package.

**In other words**, when you using this node for the nuget package of the **Project C**, and other projects which has a reference to **Project C**, other projects cannot access the nuget package and it is only the private property of the current **Project C**.

So it cannot solve your needs and cannot deal with the dependency of the nuget package.

**Solution 1**

Just use `Delete` task, add this in your project which references the **MyHelper** nuget package:

```
<Target Name="RemoveTheFiles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
        
        <ItemGroup>
            <File Include="$(TargetDir)B.dll">          
            </File>
        </ItemGroup>

        <Delete Files="@(File)"></Delete>
                    
</Target>
```